# how to pass null character to the c gets function? or terminate the input with a \0 character

Tags: c, null

I am trying to reverse engineer a binary file

now its needed that i have to pass a long string such as

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\0"
```

and it has to be terminated with a null character at last

how to pass the null character to the Puts function?

please guide me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear. What exactly do you want to do?

In nearly all C functions strings are "NUL terminated". This means that there is no information about the length of a string but the "NUL" byte at the end.

And the C compiler automatically adds a NUL byte at the end of string constants.

Example: `puts("Hello")` actually means: `puts("Hello\0")`.

So if you want to know how to pass a NUL-terminated string to a C function: Simply pass the string to the C function; the compiler will add the NUL byte automatically.

The function `puts` has no chance to find out the "real" length of the string if there are "NUL" characters inside the string: `puts("Hello\0 world")` is the same as `puts("Hello")`.

So if you want to write a "NUL" byte to the output, you have to use a function that does **not** take a NUL-terminated string. You might use the `write` or the `fwrite` function.

Example: Use `fwrite("Hello\0 world\n",1,13,stdout)` instead of `puts("Hello\0 world")`